# how can I hide an element inside iFrame using Jquery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how can hide an element inside an iframe using either JQuery , javascript or CSS
I tried to do that but JQuery can't recognize the id of that element and CSS code couldn't work also
is there any way that I can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the content of the iframe if its loaded from a different domain.
Like your parent page is abc.com and the content in your iframe is from xyz.com